# Stack Snippets Upgrade: Virtual Console

Tags: discussion, feedback, stack-snippets, stack-snippets-console

It's been a long time since we worked on Stack Snippets. I'm sorry. It's mostly because I created it, then I got promoted to management, and now I don't code much anymore and nobody else has time to work on it. So you can blame me.

But before you *do* blame me, read on for good news!

Thanks in large part to the efforts of [canon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/159427/canon) and his [MIT licensed virtual console library for Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279053/262550), we now have a virtual console!

Normally I'd do screenshots, but with Stack Snippets I can just give you a live demo instead. Check it out!

```js
console.log("virtual!");
console.log("console!");
```

```html
<b>Here's some HTML</b>
```

The system now offers a new "include console" checkbox in the editor window, which is **selected by default**. If you hate this new virtual console, you can either unselect it there, or set `console: false` in the Stack Snippet markdown. So everybody wins!

Special thanks again to [canon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/159427/canon) who did most of the work on this upgrade!

Comment: Awesome, good job!

Comment: **Thank you @canon!!**

Comment: YES YES YES! This is the best thing since stack snippets :D

Comment: Note to self: don't implement a console or you might get promoted again

Comment: Not working in Firefox (`"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"`) but works in Chrome (`"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2723.2 Safari/537.36"`). Haven't had time to debug but just quick report.

Comment: Doesn't work with http://stackoverflow.com/a/21457293/259953 :( Thus, it's useless

Comment: Answering questions yesterday, it was ***so nice*** not having to include my workaround for this!!

Comment: This needs to be [tag:featured]!

Comment: Good work, though here is [one problem/issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323556/bug-in-stack-snippet) that I think needs to be addressed ASAP

Comment: Work on this stuff seems to have stalled again. [This comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279420/stack-snippets-upgrade-virtual-console/279476#comment905759_279434) from more than two weeks ago says a minor change will be "in the next build" but it still isn't there; [this significant enhancement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279476/134069) that canon's made to the script doesn't seem to be getting any UI attention. Could we please get those in? canon's done the hard work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes it has stalled for the moment. We're still working on it but other things internally have taken priority for a few weeks.

Comment: I have create [tag:stack-snippets-console] to be able to discuss, report, and propose about the console in a proper way.

Answer (score 17):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) The console script has been moved to the head and now it waits until `DOMContentLoaded`, so console elements are inserted at the end of the body.

---

The console element should be inserted at the end of the body, just like the script one.

For example, the following code should log `Hello!` instead of `<div class="as-console"></div>`.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>Hello!</div>
```

It seems the problem is in `content/Js/snippet-javascript.en.js`

```
'writeResult': function () {
  var t = this,
  n = t._state.css,
  i = t._state.js,
  a = t._state.html,
  r = t._state.console;
  if ('' != n || '' != i || '' != a) {
    var o = '';
    null != p && (o = '//' + p),
    r === !0 && (a = '<script src="' + o + '/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js"></script>' + a);
```

The last assignment should be

```
a += '<script src="' + o + '/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js"></script>'
```

Comment: Nice catch! ...

Comment: Now that I think about it, `querySelector` is just the tip of the iceberg. Even if moved to the end, console elements will be affected by CSS and alter the length of `querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByTagName` collections. The proper way would be moving the user input inside an iframe, and place the console in the outer page.

Comment: [This is already creating problems](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323556/1529630)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Read up [on this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323556/bug-in-stack-snippet) and help getting this fixed ASAP

Comment: I ran into it in a snippet just yesterday, as I was going to do an example with a series of divs and opened it with `document.querySelectorAll("div")`. Moving it to the end may help some, but then it'll get mixed with any dynamically-added content, and wouldn't have helped in my case yesterday. Having the console div in the same document *at all* is likely to be an ongoing issue. Think it needs to be moved to a frame.

Comment: @canon Assuming the iframes have same domain, it would be something like `contentIframe.contentWindow.console.log = function(){ ... }`

Comment: @canon I was thinking [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/720rL36m/). But inserting snippet contents at DOMContentLoaded would break snippets which use DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: @canon: Thanks for the head's up. FYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279420/stack-snippets-upgrade-virtual-console/279513?noredirect=1#comment906312_279561

Answer (score 14):

You cannot XSS using this method, however, the console breaks on HTML style formatting inside a log statement:

```js
console.log("<script>alert('omg');</script>");
```

Comment: @canon must be escaping thingy. `<script></script>` throws, but not `<a></a>`. `<script></script\>` doesn't throw.

Comment: Keep in mind there's no huge risk here as-is. We'll get it fixed, but Stack Snippets are *sandboxed* and secured on a 3rd party domain. Nothing bad will come of anyone's best efforts here. :)

Comment: Instead of putting the code inside of a script tag, you could use `src=` with a data URL (without base64, if you get the encoding right) to avoid this issue. (cc @canon)

Comment: Perhaps this is growing into a new feature request @canon <_<

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) The console now grows and shrinks with the available width. The box doesn't overflow any more.

---

The Stack Snippets console overflows on mobile devices if the viewport isn't wide enough.

> [image]

This is actually just a small layout bug with a wonderful feature. (Thanks Haney!)

The post in the screenshot is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279419/245360).

Comment: Fixed and live momentarily.

Comment: @Pat did you do that when viewing the full site theme, or mobile site theme?

Comment: @ShadowWizard mobile view

Comment: Oh. And now it still works for you?

Comment: I can't run the snippet any more @Sha

Comment: @Haney the snippets are not working anymore for mobile, is this on purpose?

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (this is now implemented and live)

---

The virtual console currently implements `log`, `info`, `warn`, `error`, and `clear`, but many other console methods don't write to the virtual console (just the real one):

```js
console.log("This uses the virtual console");
console.dir({o:"testing"}); // This doesn't
console.time("timed");      // This doesn't
console.timeEnd("timed");   // This doesn't
```

Aggregating data from several DSE queries (because of timeouts; links below), here are the number of questions and answers (combined) in which various console methods occur (roughly), looking only at the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tags:

```
console.log    287,489
console.error    4,291
console.dir      2,025
console.info     1,940
console.warn       979
console.time       431
console.timeEnd    407
console.clear      277
console.assert     155
console.dirxml      20
console.count       17
```

Based on that and level of difficulty, I suggest implementing:

- `dir` as an alias for `log` initially, more can be done if appropriate but the distinction is more for interactive consoles.
- `time` and `timeEnd`, as they're quite easy

It's clearly not feasible to expect that the virtual console will have a union of all of the features offered by [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console), [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh772173.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and others! But if it's going to be called `console`, I think to minimize surprise we need to ensure it implements the more commonly-used methods.

DSE query links:

- [Occurrence in questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/488829/occurrence-of-console-methods-in-questions)
- [Occurrence in answers through 2011](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/488802/occurrence-of-console-methods-in-answers-through-2011)
- [Occurrence in answers 2012 & 2013](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/488833/occurrence-of-console-methods-in-answers-2012-and-2013)
- [Occurrence in answers 2014 onward](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/488834/occurrence-of-console-methods-in-answers-2014-onward)

Comment: @canon: Fantastic! Extremely good of you to take the time to enhance SE in this way. Any idea when they'll put that on the site?

Comment: Going live in a few!

Comment: @canon: I was! :-)

Answer (score 9):

Is the date in the log really necessary ?

It doubles the height of a console line and we rarely wait more than 24 hours to see how our snippet behaves (when we do, we lose the fastest gun race and nobody sees our answer so the snippet doesn't really matter).

```js
console.log("virtual!");
console.log("console!");
```

```html
<b>Here's some HTML</b>
```

Comment: Yeah, good point. I think I'll dump the date part this morning.

Comment: Going live in a few here.

Comment: @Haney much cleaner!

Comment: @Haney: Nice one!

Comment: TBH the time isn't probably useful either...

Comment: Could be, for demonstrating how long something takes.

Answer (score 8):

**Move the console outside the document**.

Placing the console inside the document can produce lots of interferences. For example:

- CSS selectors like `div` will select console elements
- JS collections like `document.querySelectorAll('div')` will include console elements

I think the proper way would be:

- Move the HTML, CSS and JS entered by the user inside an inner content iframe which occupies all the snippet iframe.
- Place the console in the snippet iframe, outside the content iframe

This is how the console behaves in a browser. The content of a page can't interfere with the console.

Here's a simple example of how the console being in the same document is a problem:

```js
console.log("This is...");
setTimeout(function() {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("...a problem"));
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}, 0);
```

```css
div {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

```html
<div>Hmmm</div>
```

Here's another example:

```js
// Demonstration that `length` on the jQuery instance will be 0
// if there are no matching elements. There are no `div` elements
// in this snippet.
$(function() {
  console.log($("div").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That demonstration should be logging 0, not 2. Moving the console out of the document entirely is the only way to prevent this kind of cross-talk between the console and the various different snippets people use to demonstrate things.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this bug. I have modified Stack Snippets to include the console in the `<head>` tag which alleviates DOM assumptions. This fix is now live.

Comment: @Haney Thanks, but that can't work directly. The console script appends some elements to `document.body`, so that will throw an error in the head. Better [move the script to the end of the body](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279513/195099), or use an event listener in the head.

Comment: It has been modified to use an event listener, not to worry!

Comment: @Haney OK, [it was a caching problem](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) XD

Comment: @Haney: While moving the script is a start, the bigger problem is that the console adds elements to `body`, which interact with the snippet. Have to strongly disagree with [the statement](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4935278#4935278) that the cost/benefit isn't there. Not only worth doing, but as Oriol points out, it needs doing soon. Here's an example of how it could work: http://output.jsbin.com/wicofa (Source: [main page](https://jsbin.com/himarux/edit?html), [console page](https://jsbin.com/wicofa/edit?html), [example snippet](https://jsbin.com/kazebu/edit?html))

Comment: @Haney: Sorry, the first JSBin link above is to the wrong page. Here's the example: https://output.jsbin.com/himarux

Comment: @canon: Great! Can't imagine you need any help, but the offer's there if you like. I know I've said it before, but I'll just say it one last time: I really appreciate your work on this, and I know I'm not the only one who does. It's rubbish that the only reason this is moving forward is that you're doing the work, but it's really great you're doing the work and we're fortunate to have you doing it.

Answer (score 6):

"Show console" (the label on the checkbox for enabling the feature as of the current UI; previously "include console") doesn't say much of anything. I suggest "Use in-snippet console" or similar, with one of those little (i) icons next to it with a fuller sentence.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, gonna spend a few working something more informative up. Thanks!

Comment: Done and live in next build.

Comment: @Haney: When does that build go live? And will it include a UI for [the new options](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279476/134069)?

Comment: This idea was recently raised as [a standalone question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292368/show-console-in-javascript-html-css-snippet).

Answer (score 6):

**THIS IS NOW IMPLEMENTED IN THE SCRIPT** ([demo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239456/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/279495#279495)). Just waiting for SE to add a UI for it.

---

Could we add a flag saying that the console is the entire output? This would do two things:

1. Let the console fill the result area
2. Default to *not* scrolling to the end on ouput (leaving the scrolling up to the user)

In the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, I post a **lot** of answers where the console output is the only output of the snippet. In those snippets, all of the Result area other than the virtual console is just wasted space. So how 'bout a "console is result" or similar checkbox:

[image: "console is result" option]

The default would be off, of course.

Here's an example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535661/157247) — here's the snippet currently in that answer, using my rubbish workaround `snippets.js` script:

```js
var str = "j and j and j x";
snippet.log("Search string: '" + str + "'");
for (var n = 0; n < str.length; ++n) {
  test(str, n);
}
function test(s, start) {
  var index = s.indexOf("j", start);
  snippet.log("Starting at " + start + ": " + index);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

And here it is with the lovely virtual console canon wrote for us:

```js
var str = "j and j and j x";
console.log("Search string: '" + str + "'");
for (var n = 0; n < str.length; ++n) {
  test(str, n);
}
function test(s, start) {
  var index = s.indexOf("j", start);
  console.log("Starting at " + start + ": " + index);
}
```

As you can see, it shows the *end* of the output rather than the beginning, a lot more scrolling is required, and clicking the "Full page" link doesn't help.

Comment: i second that, but i would request a variable splitter, too, because the console output is fixed in size and it would be better if the size can be adjusted.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Thanks. I'd post the variable thing as a separate suggestion. This one is just a simple all-or-nothing.

Comment: I'd love to hear from the downvoters why they don't think this would be useful. I'd be using it every day, several *times* a day.

Comment: @canon: **You rock.** Yes, normal consoles scroll (well, most do) and we want what you originally did as the default, no question. But the use case for most of my answers is more `document.write`-like, e.g., just output that usually should be read from the top down. (I just refuse to use `document.write` and lead people into bad habits. :-) ). So your `autoScroll: false` and `maximize` options work perfectly for that. Hope to see a way from SE to use it soon!

Comment: @canon: BTW, happy to pitch in if you ever want another pair of hands in there. Just say the word. You clearly don't need the help on a technical level, but everyone has time limitations.

Answer (score 4):

When throwing errors, it would be helpful to actually print the line that the error occurred on, especially as the line mentioned doesn't match up with the source code. Of course, it's good that it shows anything for errors.

```js
console.log('console!!')
console.log([1,2,3])
console.log({i: 'think', this: 'is', cool: '!'})
console.log(console.log)
throw new Error('test')
```

Comment: Not only JS-only, but for any error that comes from the JS code, if that's possible.

Comment: Correct, but here at least we have some measure of control over what it shows. ;)

Comment: Or instead of adjusting the line number, just give the line of code the error occurred on, as i actually wrote in the answer.

Comment: This needs more upvotes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Do not include the console by default**, at least until it has been stabilized.

Including the console has collateral effects like [Bug in stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323556/1529630).

People which creates snippets may not realize that this is a bug which (hopefully) will be fixed. So they might rely on the buggy behavior.

Then, once the fix lands, these snippets will break.

Not including the console by default would alleviate this possibility. Moreover, even if the console will be useful to lots of snippets, I think they are still a minority.

Only once the console has been stabilized, it might be considered to enable it by default.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this bug. I have modified Stack Snippets to include the console in the `<head>` tag which alleviates DOM assumptions. This fix is now live.

Answer (score 3):

[**I can't put a bounty on this answer, so I've raised a formal feature-request instead.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284754/implement-a-ui-for-the-stack-snippet-console-options) If you want this done, please go upvote and or bounty as appropriate.

<s>@canon has [implemented several useful options in the script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279420/stack-snippets-upgrade-virtual-console/279476#comment905849_279476) (there's a [demo here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279495/134069)). Please add a UI for them so people don't start using `console.config` directly.</s>

I'd suggest making it a Console Options button or some such that shows options driven by the script itself, so that when an option is added to the script, the UI for it can be added at the same time. The options would be serialized to JSON and inserted in  the stack snippet's introductory comment node.

For instance, where a snippet might currently start with this:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true -->
```

If the user uses the dialog to set options, it might look like this:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true console-options: {"maximize":true,"autoScroll":false} -->
```

Those options get converted into a hidden call to `console.config` at the beginning of the snippet script.

Answer (score 3):

Logging events directly to the console causes the browser to *whirrr* for a couple of seconds (probably trying to stringify the whole subtree), and throw some errors (in the same console).

Also, it takes a lot longer than necessary to execute the `console.log` statement (due to the entire stringification process I guess.)

It currently takes roughly 2-3 seconds for me in Chrome 61. Here's how it looks in the browser console:

[image]

```js
function clicked(event) {
  var startTime = new Date();
  console.log(event);
  var endTime = new Date();
  
  console.log("Total time (ms): " + (endTime - startTime));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clicked(event)">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Almost 16 seconds for me