# Specific Post Crashes iOS Client

Tags: bug, ios-app

The following Puzzling post reliably crashes the iOS client: [Make 20 using two threes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/35081/17775)

To repro, load the post and scroll down through the answers. Once you get partway down, the app crashes out to the home screen.

My device is a 128GB iPhone 6s Plus (CDMA) running stock iOS 9.3.2. Client version is 1.5.0.3.

Comment: I was able to scroll to the bottom of the last comment on the last answer on that post on my iPhone 5S iOS 9.3.2.

Comment: Well, there are lots of content there maybe that's the issue. Try browsing [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279420/stack-snippets-upgrade-virtual-console) with your app and see.

Comment: There is definitely a crasher that *loves* to happen on certain Puzzling questions. Were you doing anything other than scrolling? Did you do expand comments?

Comment: Fwiw I can no longer repro the crash with the current state of the question. @BrianNickel I was scrolling and expanding the *spoiler* sections.

Comment: Thanks.  It's an issue that happens a couple times a day across all users (too few to repro) but I just got a flood of crashes in Puzzling.  I'm adding a *lot* of logging to the next release of the app so hopefully I'll be able to track down the root cause.