# "Show console" in "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-snippets-console

The advanced options in "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" all have help icons except "Show console", so:

1. Could you add a help icon there too?
2. Can you describe here exactly what it does?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [Stack Snippets Upgrade: Virtual Console](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279420/307988)

The option just gives you a virtual console to output to (rather than relying on your browsers console). The virtual console is only visible if there is something to show so you need to actually use it for it to be visible:

> [image]

As [T.J. Crowder's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279434/307988), the option would probably be better named:

> ☑ Use in-snippet console

With a (i) and tooltip of something along the lines of:

> Enable the virtual console below the snippet (only visible if there is console output)

Which would look something like this:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Q1 should be done by developers.

Q2. What it does

This is to show/hide console.

First read and understand what a console do from here [console documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2288/console).

The above is for browser console.

In snippet, console act like a browser console but readonly.
You can't run scripts directly on console like in browser but all activity which `console` involved will be shown in the bottom of the output screen.

For example,

```
  console.log('hello world');
```

If you run the above in snippet with `show console`, then you can see a **hello world** in the bottom of the output screen.

Also errors are logged in console