# Can't run Stack code Snippets on the mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web, stack-snippets

Is it a known issue that stack snippets don't have the "Run code snippet" button underneath on the mobile version of the site? [Searching for this yielded nothing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=stack+snippets), both on MSE and MSO.

I've posted a 500-points bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094908/google-maps-keep-center-when-zooming) about pinch zooming in Google Maps on mobile, and the ability to run the solution code snippets on an actual touch screen device is critical.

Do I need to ask the bounty contestants to include a JSFiddle link because code snippets don't run in the mobile site?

Comment: No, snippets don't run on mobile (you can hit the "mobile" button and see they won't even run in your desktop browser in the mobile view)... surprised I can't find that documented anywhere though

Comment: @Cai no need to document it IMO, mobile theme got only the basic features, by design. To get all the "cool" stuff, one can simply switch to full site view, even on mobile device. (But then it can look weird of course.)

Comment: Hmmm, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279427/307988) says it at least used to work on mobile; pretty sure I've never seen it on mobile though...

Comment: The question about bounty is not related, maybe can be asked as a separate discussion.

Comment: @Sha if it was documented somewhere then I wouldn't be so confused by it now ;)

Comment: Actually when using Firefox mobile and setting desktop view it allows to run the snippets. It seems that this has been intentionally removed so yeah, a short explanation on the "why" would be great.