# Snippets can be formatted in monospace

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-snippets

[Example answer with bug.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59023209/11091039)

By indenting the snippet generating comments, you can make a pretty odd snippet style, where the button titles are shown in a monospaced font.

```
let test = "Hello, world!";
<html>
<body>
Test
</body>
</html>
```

Image for those on mobile:

[image]

Comment: This is hilarious.

Comment: I don't get it? What's wrong? Im on mobile, maybe it looks different to me

Comment: @dustytrash, I confirm that a mobile version shows snippets incorrectly (it should look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhbGs.png), but actually looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2eUq.png)). I'm filing a report on it.

Comment: @dustytrash, denied reporting, it looks like status-bydesign: [Can't run Stack code Snippets on the mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293274/357761).

Comment: @JL2210 I wonder how many levels in you can go...

Answer (score 1):

Eh... The snippet editor itself should never produce output like this... You have to go out of your way to trigger it, at which point it looks completely broken in the editor preview:

[image: snippet appears as "<pre>sif647</pre>" in the preview]

If your goal is to make your post look weird or broken, you can do that in many ways. And if you really want to involve snippets, you can get a hell of a lot crazier than just monospaced text...

## ```
let test = "Hello, world!";
<html>
<body>
Test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't it something that should be fixed if a lot of people start abusing it?

Comment: Why? Folks can put all sorts of stupid stuff in their posts. That's why we have flagging and editing.

Comment: So should we edit this to remove the broken snippet editor? ;)

Comment: TL;DR: It's not a bug, it's a feature.