# Deploy updated snippet script and implement a UI for the Stack Snippet console options

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Back in May 2016 [@canon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/621962/canon) implemented [several useful options in the Stack Snippets console script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279420/stack-snippets-upgrade-virtual-console/279476#comment905849_279476) (there's a [demo here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279495/134069)). Please

1. Deploy the updated script so those options can be used (currently, only `maxEntries` works), and
2. Add a UI for them so people don't use `console.config` directly, or resort to adding irrelevant CSS to their answers ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595014/157247)). Or at least support hand-edited options in the snippet comment markup in the short term before a UI is available.

On the UI, I'd suggest making it a Console Options button or some such that shows options driven by the script itself, so that when an option is added to the script, the UI for it can be added at the same time so we don't have multi-month lag between implementation and availability. The options would be serialized to JSON and inserted in the stack snippet's introductory comment node.

For instance, where a snippet might currently start with this:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true -->
```

If the user uses the dialog to set options, it might look like this:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true console-options: {"maximize":true,"autoScroll":false} -->
```

Those options get converted into a hidden call to `console.config` at the beginning of the snippet script.

---

(I [raised this at the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279987/134069) but as nothing's happened and you can't bounty an answer, I'm posting a proper [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).)