# Snack snippets sandbox makes Chrome web browser unresponsive

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

**The sandbox linked to in the [[snack-snippets] tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/stack-snippets/info) makes my browser sluggish/unresponsive.** My CPU usage jumps to 25%, so I think there are either too many snippets, or some of them require too many resources.

- Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit)
- FireFox is initially sluggish, but returns to normal speed after a few seconds. (Version 49.0.2)

Direct link to the sandbox (you have been warned!!): [Stack Snippets Sandbox: Try It Out Here!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239456/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here)

Comment: Nothing noticeable here. I even ran *all* the snippets (and that includes things like a WebGL Minecraft demo) and the page wasn't noticeably slower.

Comment: No issue for me, the page loads instantly in Chrome 54.0.2840.98.